# Is it possible to make a geodatabase feature class invisible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, tools, reports

I am working on creating a report for a customer that requires using a couple tools in arcmap then export values to a dbf. They then have to run a crystal report that pulls data from Oracle in the cloud that we have granted restricted access.

I want to create a report directly in arcmap that would be incorporated into a tool, but I can't figure out how to access that data needed for the report without incorporating the restricted data (eg, using a fc with the data).  Is there a way to have a feature class embedded in a gdb but restrict the access to that fc so that the customer doesn't see it?

I understand this is not ideal, but it is kind of a bandaid till we get the funding to build out our online tool.

Comment: Looks like I can't do this without SDE.  Are there any other solutions besides ArcSDE?

Comment: Can the restricted data be used to create a separate version of the data that would not be restricted by removing fields that the report does not include?  Or is the shape location itself restricted and/or the report must have access to restricted fields to generate report summaries that are specific for each user request?  Basically, can a layer be created that only includes the data in the format you would release through the report anyway?

Comment: @RichardFairhurst If I understand you correctly, no it is not possible to release the data in the layer that is available through the report.  That is out of my hands.  We basically provide a blind dataset of our data that only has a ID value.  Crystal Reports uses those values to fetch the data from Oracle to generate the report.

Comment: I don't know if you are understanding me or not.  Some portion of the data beyond the ID is being released in the report you are creating, otherwise the report and the data have no reason to interact.  Whether or not it is actually possible to create such a layer, if the layer could effectively show no data other than what the report shows, would you be able to make that layer available to the user?  If not, then you may as well make them wait until your cloud based solution is ready.

Comment: I can create a layer with the data that is generated from the report, but I cannot make it available to the user. I can however, create that layer and have it available for the data requests that are processed in-house.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with a file geodatabase.  If the user has rights to the directory it is in they can access all parts of it the same as any other part.  SDE would be required to apply security that would make the feature class invisible to the user and yet accessible to the tool through a secure connection using code.  You would also have to apply password protection to any python file or addin used to create the tool or develop the tool in Visual Basic using ArcObjects.